# data is not insert to my database table

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'not connected to server';
        }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'user_table'))
    {
        echo 'database not selected';
        }

    $mobilenumber = $_POST['mobilenumber'];
    $operator = $_POST['operator'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];

    $sql =  "INSERT INTO user_details (mobilenumber,operator,state) VALUES ('".$mobilenumber."','".$operator."','".$state."')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        echo 'not inserted';
        }
    else
    {
        echo 'inserted';
        }

    //$select="insert into user_details (mobilenumber,operator,state) VALUES ('".$mobilenumber."".$operator."".$state."')";
    //$sql=mysql_query($select);

    //print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    //print 'alert("the data is inserted.....")';
    //print '<script>';
    //mysql_close();
?>

<form method="post" action="insert.php" id="submitForm">

<select id="operator" type="select" ng-model="operatorName" ng-class="operatorError ? 'error-border':''" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Select operator" ng-click="showOperators($event);" name="operator" method=POST action=/insert.php class="form-control fetchoperators drpdwn-arrow ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" required>

<select name="state" class="state" id="state" required name="state" method="post" action="insert.php">
```

Comment: Do you expect anyone to even attempt answering this when you just post code....?

Comment: Brother add the response what is message (Response).

Comment: Do you have any error? What the current output? More over, if you are not able to connect to DB, you shall to continue trying the rest, Please try to be explicit and to pin point your problem OR at least, what you tried. Help people who freely helps you!

Comment: use <input type="submit" /> for submitting from may be it will help you to resolve problem

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest way is to try to debug your query.
What i would have done is simply the process as much as i could firt.

do `echo $sql;`

Then copy the result and paste it in the my sql server if that works.

Then check your connection object apparently it's look right but the best way of doing this copy the following code. and try this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "user_table";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql =  "INSERT INTO user_details (mobilenumber,operator,state) VALUES ('".$mobilenumber."','".$operator."','".$state."')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

change the credentials and check the response and paste it in the comments then we will go along.

Comment: your code seems like static there is no $varible every time action will insert same result

Comment: Brother i clearly said you have change it ,. anyway please try the i have describe and i have updated the whole code for you to try ,. now copy and paste

Comment: you should verify the dbname ,., is it the same dbname as yours

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
  mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die((mysql_error());
```

it will show you error for which it is not inserting data in you table